# Relation Between Eigenvalues of Certain Block Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, permutation-matrices

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
cI & P & Q \\
P^\top & cI & R\\
Q^\top & R^\top & cI\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ be a **block matrix** where $P$, $Q$ and $R$ are $n\times n$ matrices with real entries and $c$ is a real number.  Let $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$ be $n\times n$ **permutation matrices**. Let
$B= 
\begin{bmatrix}
cI & P_1P & P_2Q \\
(P_1P)^\top & cI & P_3R\\
(P_2Q)^\top & (P_3R)^\top & cI\\ 
\end{bmatrix}\\$.
Is there any relation between the **eigenvalues** of $A$ and $B$? I have tried using computer programming for obtaining eigenvalues of all possible combinations of $B$ but the output obtained runs to  pages and looking for patterns in this is getting extremely tedious.
Also, Is there any theory that one could apply for comparing the eigenvalues of A and B?

Comment: Supposing that you did not find any patters yet, is there any reason why you think that such a pattern might exist? This does not seem a kind of question that comes up naturally from simple curiosity.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I came across this kind of structure while studying adjacency matrices of regular tripartite graphs.